# Armadillo with MinGW G++ faulty executable on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, crash, mingw, armadillo

If I try to compile the code

```
  #include "armadillo"

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  }
```

using MinGW g++ and latest armadillo (3.6.1), it works fine on my windows XP, but if I compile it and the run it on windows 7 then I get: "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly."

What could cause this?

I have tried with both 4.6.2 and 4.7.2 (g++ -v of latest included next):

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/lto-wrapper.exe Target: mingw32 Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure
>   --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,obj c,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgo mp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug
>   --disable-build-poststage1- with-cxx --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw Thread model: win32 gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)

Note that at this stage I am not even linking any library like LAPACK.
I also tried uncommenting

> //#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK

in config.cpp, but to no effect.
By the way, I can compile c code without armadillo no problem on both systems.  It is only the addition of the armadillo include that causes problems.

Update: If I press ctrl-c I get:

> forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event Image
>   PC        Routine            Line        Source lapack_win32_MT.d 
>   103A49EA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown lapack_win32_MT.d 
>   1034CD0E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown lapack_win32_MT.d 
>   1035B254  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown kernel32.dll
>   755B6C19  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown kernel32.dll
>   75513677  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown ntdll.dll
>   77DFC002  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown ntdll.dll
>   77DFBFD5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Update: On yet another windows 7 system, I do manage to execute but I get the following message at compile time (when compiling example2.cpp in the armadillo package):

```
Info: resolving vtable for std::exception by linking to __imp___ZTVSt9exception (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for std::bad_alloc by linking to __imp___ZTVSt9bad_alloc (auto-import)
Info: resolving std::cout  by linking to __imp___ZSt4cout (auto-import)
Info: resolving std::nothrow  by linking to __imp___ZSt7nothrow (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info by linking to __imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info by linking to __imp___ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (auto-import)
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on the command line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols from auto-imported DLLs.
```

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear - are you compiling on the Win7 system(s) as well?  Or are you compiling on the XP system and copying the binary over to the Win7 systems.  And what versions of MinGW are involved (I see that 4.5.0 is in the dump above, but is that on the XP or one of the Win7 systems)?  And does a hello world program that doesn't include the armadillo header behave the same way?

Comment: I am compiling on the Win7 system.  A "hello world" program works fine.  But the same program with just the armadillo include crashes.  I am using g++ 4.6.2 (I have included the output of g++ -v) in the question for it's too long.

Comment: Are you also building armadillo, or are you linking to pre-built library?

Comment: I am not building armadillo.  I am linking to the blas and lapack provided with it.